# Stuck with this issue of eventlistener with list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Have been trying to solve this problem for so long

I have a list called datalist in which I am storing data from firebase in order to use it in the recyclerview.

But the problem is inside childeventlistener the list is getting updated but before this happens return call is made and it ends up in a null list.

What should be done?

```
package com.example.dell.hungryapp;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Dell on 5/29/2017.
 */

public class itemmodel {
public String item_name;
public  int quantity;


public String getItem_name() {
    return item_name;
}

public void setItem_name(String item_name) {
    this.item_name = item_name;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}


public static List<itemmodel> getObjectList(){


    final List<itemmodel> datalist=new ArrayList<>();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();




    databaseReference.child("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("Inventory").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           System.out.println("value is : "+dataSnapshot.getValue());

           String id=dataSnapshot.getKey();
           Integer qty=dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);

           itemmodel item=new itemmodel();
           item.setItem_name(id);
           item.setQuantity(qty);

           datalist.add(item);

           System.out.println("before size : "+datalist.size());

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });



    System.out.println("before size : "+datalist.size());
    return datalist;


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow this link if you want to retrieve the whole data from inventory. I have used maps in order to retrieve the whole data and stored it in array list

```
final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("users").child(users.getUid).child("Inventory");
```

[Remove the previous markers as the location updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857313/remove-the-previous-markers-as-the-location-updates?noredirect=1#comment70928717_41857313)

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: hi @akshay naik i am afraid it couldnt solve my problem still datalist is showing null after return